# Show that Va and Vb -> Vc

Tags: logic

Just to preface, I am not looking for the answer, I want to confirm that I understood this problem correctly and that I also came to a right conclusion.

Here it is:

> Show that
>
> if p1,p2 / ∴ p and p,p3...pn / ∴ C
>
> are valid arguments, the
>   argument
>
> p1,p2,...pn / ∴ C is also valid

This is from Discrete Mathematics by Richard Johnsonbaugh (exercice 16 of page 36).

We can express the validity of p1,p2 / ∴ p by Va

We can express the validity of p,p3...pn / ∴ C by Vb

We can expresss the validity of p1,p2,...pn / ∴ C by Vc

The problem then becomes

If Va and Vb, then Vc.

We can check the first premise with a truth table:

(Where 0 is false and 1 is true)

[Truth table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kn8pC.png)

We now have:

If false and Vb, then Vc

Which we can simplify as :

False then Vc

Which is false implies Vc.

We then get false -> Vc, which is always true.

We can then say that:

> if p1,p2 / ∴ p and p,p3...pn / ∴ C
>
> are valid arguments, the
>   argument
>
> p1,p2,...pn / ∴ C is also valid

I am wondering if this is valid reasoning, and a correct answer for the problem.

If not, I am just wondering where I went wrong about it.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your reasoning is quite difficult to understand...

Comment: How so? What can I do to make it easier to understand?

Comment: "We can express the validity of p1,p2 / ∴ p by Va". What is Va ?

Comment: "The problem then becomes: If Va and Vb, then Vc. We can check the first premise with a truth table..." You have reduced the initial problem to a propositional formula: "$(Va \land Vb) \to Vc$". And then ... ?

Answer (score 0):

No, truth tables won't help you.  You have to argue the metalogic.

Basically you wish to show that if "$\Sigma \vdash p$" and "$p, \Gamma\vdash C$" , then "$\Sigma, \Gamma \vdash C$" , where $\Sigma$ is "$p_1,p_2$", and $\Gamma$ is "$p_3,\ldots,p_n$".

Well if "$\Sigma\vdash p$" , then "$\Sigma,\Gamma\vdash p$", because (why)?

Now if "$p,\Gamma\vdash C$", then "$\Gamma\vdash \text{(what?)}$", because (why?), and so as above "$\Sigma,\Gamma\vdash \text{(what?)}$".

And if "$\Sigma,\Gamma\vdash p$", and "$\Sigma,\Gamma\vdash \text{(what?)}$", then "$\Sigma,\Gamma\vdash C$", because (why?).

(Fill in the why and what.)

---

$\vdash$ is your $/\!\therefore$